# Склонение слова участковый

Tags: склонение

Затрудняюсь: как написать "при прячущимся от нас участков...м" (О или Ы)?
Спасибо.
Олег Крюк.

Comment: Вы точно хотите включить в ваш текст именно эту фразу? Ее трудно и написать, и прочитать. Может стоит переформулировать?

Comment: В оригинале было еще безобразней: при ныкающемся участковом. Контекст обязывал.

Answer (score 6):

(При ком?) При участковОМ. (Каком?) ПрячущЕМся. При прячущемся участковом.

Comment: Спасибо! Не сразу нашел способ поблагодарить: три инсульта за плечами это вам не хрен собачий. - "А собачачий",- всегда поправлял меня светлой памяти тренер.